# Whenever I setup react.js and than import any external link (Material UI or Bootstrap React) entire screen get disabled and turned into white?

Tags: reactjs, npm, react-hooks, react-bootstrap, react-error-boundary

I have setup my react.js eairler, everytime I import bootstrap related thing (Container, Row, Col, etc) and than put it on the application, the screen turns out to be white.

HTML and CSS get to be completely disabled, web page turn into completely white. What do you think the solution for this problem?

Comment: please check console logs and network tab logs and see it helps you or you can add those here to let community help you.

Answer (score 0):

Have you followed the setup guide from react-bootstrap?

https://react-bootstrap.github.io/getting-started/introduction

Also, maybe your browser javascript is disabled, try another browser, and when you inspect the page, do you can see the bootstrap elements?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).